# Is there a way to create Google document in specific folder of Google Drive through Google API PHP SDK?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I've checked updating permissions per user or group, but it doesn't seem viable in my case because users, who will be creating docs from application, won't be added manually. Is there are way to specify folder (other than root in Google Drive) that will be used with every insert request to place document in it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the folder id of the directory you would like the file created in as the parents in the metadata.

```
 $service = new Google_DriveService($client);
  // Create the file on your Google Drive
  $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'My file',
    'parents' => ['FILEIDOFFOLDER']));
  $content = file_get_contents($target_file);
  $mimeType=mime_content_type($target_file);
  $file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
    'data' => $content,
    'mimeType' => $mimeType,
    'fields' => 'id'));
  printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);
```